# Array of pointers to an object in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am trying to write a super basic program which creates an array of objects under class `Receipt`. The class includes an *int* price, *string* good (name), and a simple function that adds an item to the list. I am stuck because every time I compile it seg faults before it even gets to the add function, meaning something is wrong with my default constructor.

I am still really new to C++ and pointers are probably my biggest struggle. I have looked online and at my lecture notes trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I feel like it's something small but I cannot figure it out.

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Receipt {
private:
    int price;
    string good;
    Receipt* goods[500]; //partially filled array
public:
    Receipt();
    void add(string name, int cost);
    string getName();
    int getPrice();
    void setName(string name_in);
    void setPrice(int price_in);
    void displayList();
};

Receipt::Receipt()
{       
    for (int i=0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        goods[i]->setName("Empty");
        goods[i]->setPrice(-1);
    }
}

void Receipt::add(string name, int cost)
{
    int place=0;
    for (int i=0; i <500; i++)
    {
        if (goods[i]->getName()=="Empty" && goods[i]->getPrice()==-1)
        {
            place = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    goods[place]->setName(name);
    goods[place]->setPrice(cost);
}

int Receipt::getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

string Receipt::getName()
{
    return good;
}

void Receipt::setName(string name_in)
{
    good = name_in;
}

void Receipt::setPrice(int price_in)
{
    price = price_in;
}

void Receipt::displayList()
{
    //just displaying first item in list for debugging purposes
    cout << goods[0]->getName() << endl << goods[0]->getPrice();
}


int main()
{
    Receipt mine; //seg faults here 

    mine.add("banana", 50);
    mine.displayList();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have array of pointers but they point nowhere.

Comment: `Receipt` consists of array of pointers to `Receipt`, it is very bad design.

Comment: Every instance of a receipt contains 500 pointers to other receipts.  (oops)  You might consider making the array static, so all elements share the same storage.  And while your fixing that, I suggest using std::vector<Receipt*>,  and until you can identify the reason for it, do not pre-allocate the array. Use push_back().  Much more flexible and very much more C++.

Comment: You seem to not fully understand how pointers work.  Pointers can have only a fixed amount of memory allocated to them.

You can't have a pointer to the container class string.  That is a type that grows dynamically.  A pointer element needs something with a fixed amount of memory.You allocate a fixed amount of memory to a pointer element, not something that allocates an open ended amount of memory.Use char type.

Furthermore, the design of the program doesn't seem to want to use pointers.  A new element for receipt array doesn't declare a new section of memory for each element of receipt.

Answer (score 1):

your design is wrong, you have array of Receipt inside Receipt so when you initialize the object, it create 500 where each of them create another 500 endlessly. I think you want to create something like this instead

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Receipt {
private:
    int price;
    string good;

public:

    void setName(string name_in);
    void setPrice(int price_in);
    string getName();
    int getPrice();
};


class Receipts {
private:
    Receipt* goods[500]; //partially filled array
public:
    Receipts();

    void add(string name, int cost);
    void displayList();
};

Receipts::Receipts()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        goods[i] = new Receipt();
        goods[i]->setName("Empty");
        goods[i]->setPrice(-1);
    }
}

void Receipts::add(string name, int cost)
{
    int place = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <500; i++)
    {
        if (goods[i]->getName() == "Empty" && goods[i]->getPrice() == -1)
        {
            place = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    goods[place]->setName(name);
    goods[place]->setPrice(cost);
}

int Receipt::getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

string Receipt::getName()
{
    return good;
}

void Receipt::setName(string name_in)
{
    good = name_in;
}

void Receipt::setPrice(int price_in)
{
    price = price_in;
}

void Receipts::displayList()
{
    //just displaying first item in list for debugging purposes
    cout << goods[0]->getName() << endl << goods[0]->getPrice();
}


int main()
{
    Receipts mine; //seg faults here 

    mine.add("banana", 50);
    mine.displayList();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is your `delete`?

Comment: @NickyC i just use the original code and there's no delete there

Comment: Good correction of pointers pointing to nowhere.  Unfortunately, you can't have pointers creating a new receipt because one of the elements in receipt is an open ended size-string.  Pointer elements need to have a fixed size of allocated memory each.  Instead of string, use an array of characters in receipt.